# Matching A General Pattern In One String To Another

Tags: php

I have a list of poker hands stored in an array in this format:

`$hands = ['AsQdTc9h', 'AsQsTd9d' ...]`

I also have a search string that is 4 characters and uses the letters `xyzw`. For example, search string could look like:

```
$searchString = 'xyxy';
$searchString = 'xyzw';
$searchString = 'yzyw';
```

The entire purpose of the search string is to identify a desired pattern for the lowercase characters in the hand.

So if the searchString is `xyzw`, that is just a way of saying 'only select hands where none of the lowercase letters are equal.' If the search string is `xyxy`, that is a way of saying 'only select hands where the first and the third lowercase letters are equal and the second and fourth lowercase letters are equal.

In other words, the lowercase letters must match the pattern of the search string. How can I implement this in PHP?

Comment: so that means in `AsQsTd9d` the lowercase letters are `ssdd` and pattern is `xxyy` ?

Comment: @Abolix Exactly. And I think this goes without saying, but `xxyy` should also match if the lowercase letters were `ddhh`, `sshh`, `ccdd`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
$MyString = 'AsQdTc9h';
$MyString = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $MyString); // Get only the lowercase characters
// $MyString : sdch

$LetterArray = str_split($MyString);
$LetterArray = array_count_values($LetterArray);

$ReplaceList = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'];
$i = 0;
foreach ($LetterArray as $Letter => $result) {
    $MyString = str_replace($Letter, $ReplaceList[$i], $MyString);
    $i++;
}
echo $MyString; // expected output : xyzw
```

i want to explain the code so you can understand it , first we got all the lowercase characters using regex . then we turned the 4-character words to a array and then we counted how many of the characters are the same .

then we replaced the results to xyzw .

Answer (score 0):

Although this seems like a pattern matching task, due to the very limited length of the strings a pseudo-brute-force checking might be the easiest.

```
function pokerMatch(string $hand, string $pattern): bool
{
    $hand = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $hand);

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hand); $i++) {
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < strlen($hand); $j++) {
            if ($pattern[$i] === $pattern[$j] && $hand[$i] !== $hand[$j]) {
                return false;
            }
            if ($pattern[$i] !== $pattern[$j] && $hand[$i] === $hand[$j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Basically what this does, it goes over pattern string, takes each pair of characters and checks:

- if the letters in pattern positions i and j are equals then so must be the characters in the hand string;
- if the letters in pattern positions i and j are different then so must be the characters in the hand string;

If any of these doesn't hold - the pattern doesn't match

If after checking all pairs we found no mismatches - then it's a match.

Usage:

```
var_dump(pokerMatch('AsQdTc9h', 'xyzw')); // => bool(true)
var_dump(pokerMatch('AsQdTc9h', 'xyzz')); // => bool(false)
var_dump(pokerMatch('AsQsTc9c', 'xxyy')); // => bool(true)
var_dump(pokerMatch('AsQsTc9c', 'zzww')); // => bool(true) (it's agnostic to exact letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by iterating over each hand and search string, keeping a record of which suit matches which search letter, and checking that they are always consistent:

```
$hands = ['AsQdTc9h', 'AsQsTd9d', 'AsKh9s9d'];
$searchStrings = ['xyxy', 'xyzw', 'yzyw', 'ppqq'];

function match_hand($hand, $search) {
    $h = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/', '', $hand);
    $matches = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($search); $i++) {
        $s = $search[$i];
        // have we seen this search letter before? 
        if (isset($matches[$s])) {
            // does it match the previous value? if not, it's an error
            if ($matches[$s] != $h[$i]) return false;
        }
        else {
            // haven't seen this search letter before, so this hand letter should not be in the matches array yet
            if (in_array($h[$i], $matches)) return false;
        }
        $matches[$s] = $h[$i];
    }
    return true;
}

foreach ($hands as $hand) {
    foreach ($searchStrings as $search) {
        if (match_hand($hand, $search)) {
            echo "hand $hand matches pattern $search\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hand AsQdTc9h matches pattern xyzw
hand AsQsTd9d matches pattern ppqq
hand AsKh9s9d matches pattern yzyw
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/OtHG2)